# How to delete multiple selected rows of data from a listbox that uses a listobject as the rowsource in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, listobject

I have a UserForm with a listbox using a listobject as the rowsource.

I want to select multiple rows of data from the listbox, delete the corresponding data from the listobject, and then update the listbox.

```
Private Sub Delete_Click()

'Option Explicit is enabled

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim myListBox As MSForms.listbox
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
    Set myListBox = Me.listbox
    
    With myListBox
        For i = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If .Selected(i) Then
                tbl.ListRows(i + 1).Delete
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    
    myListBox.RowSource = ""
    myListBox.RowSource = tbl
End Sub
```

I had code for deleting one row. This is for trying to delete multiple rows.

I can select multiple rows of data from the listbox but it will only delete the bottommost row of data, regardless of order of selection.

Comment: Maybe try to add one variable ... `dim rgU as range`. rgU is used to collect all the selected rows of the table based on the selected item in the listbox. Then use the loop like this `For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1:If .Selected(i) and i<>0 Then If rgU Is Nothing Then Set rgU = tbl.ListRows(i).Range Else Set rgU = Union(rgU, tbl.ListRows(i).Range):next`  then add `rgU.delete:ListBox1.RowSource = .Range.Address:end with`. Please note, the listbox rowsource use tbl.address range. So, listrows start from 1 (which is row2 since row1 is table header), that's why it need `and i<>0`

Comment: Thank you karma! It actually worked very well! I did run into two issues I am trying to understand. The first error is that I receive runtime error '91' Object Variable or With block variable not set at rgU.Delete. This issue happens when I have one row left with data inside of it and I attempt to delete it. The second error happens when I delete multiple rows. It will delete all rows except the bottom one. It pushes that data up to the top.  I am just trying to understand now. I did however take the concept, if that is the right term, of rgU and made code that also works somewhat the same!

Comment: I have the code I currently have that somewhat works but I do not know the proper etiquette for posting new code or if that would now be a separate question. With that being said you helped me a lot.                                                                                                       Thank you,                                                                                                                                      Vantan

Comment: I made a mistake on this line `ListBox1.RowSource = .Range.Address`. That's why it throw you an error. Please have a look to my answer below. Without rgU, you delete the table row one by one inside the loop. With rgU, you collect/union the table row  inside the loop. Then after the loop you delete the rows in rgU at once. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake in the code in my comment which is this line `ListBox1.RowSource = .Range.Address`. It should be `ListBox1.RowSource = tbl.Range.Address`. And better, in case the sheet Data is not active : `ListBox1.RowSource = ws.Name & "!" & tbl.Range.Address`

To test the code below, create a userform with one Listbox and one command button.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
    With ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = 3
        .RowSource = ws.Name & "!" & tbl.Range.Address
        .ColumnWidths = "35,35,35"
        .MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectExtended
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rgU As Range: Dim i As Integer
If Not tbl.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
    With ListBox1
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(i) And i <> 0 Then If rgU Is Nothing Then Set rgU = tbl.ListRows(i).Range Else Set rgU = Union(rgU, tbl.ListRows(i).Range)
        Next
        rgU.Delete: .RowSource = ws.Name & "!" & tbl.Range.Address
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

The row source for the listbox use the table address, but in my comment I forgot to include the name of the sheet (which is sheet Data) in case sheet Data is not active when showing the userform. Now in the code above I include the sheet name (ws.name).

Since this is just a test sub, you need sheet Data is active before showing the userform, in order to see if it delete a correct row in the table.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help karma. I was able to get it to work! I just had to turn off my listbox1 columns head property. I was trying to get it to work with the columnheads on but it just causes a lot of issues for me. I prefer the look of the columnheads on in the listbox but am having issues with headers. I get two rows with the headers being the second row. The first row, shows per column, a,b,c and d. , respectively, a,b,c, and d. If you know why that is I would love to know how to consistently get it to work! If not thank you for the help. I'm going to apply this to more than just deletion.

Comment: You wrote : _I get two rows with the headers being the second row_. Assume row1 you have a,b and c and row2 you have AAA,BBB and CCC. In my mind, maybe when you create the table, you include row1. So your  ListObjects("Table1") start from row 1, with it's header a, b, c. Maybe that's why the listbox show a,b,c and AAA, BBB, CCC. if when you create the table you define the range starting from row 2, then your ListObjects("Table1") start from row 2, and you wouldn't see a,b and c in the Listbox but AAA, BBB and CCC.

Comment: It definitely makes sense as that was my thought too! I just need to figure out how to make it work correctly. While I have made it able to include the header information in the correct place when columnheads are turned on it gets funky after that. I'll try to delete something and then data starts getting pushed to different places.  With that being said I am gonna do my best to make that happen and if not I'll post a question with my code. Thank you for the help Karma, Vantan